# Issue with adding Upsell products under a configurable product in magento

Tags: magento

I have created a configurable product in my website and when i try to add an upsell product with this product, i get the below error

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3-1949' for key 'UNQ_product_link_attribute_id_link_id'`

I googled out this error and found the below suggestion,

"**Try to clear the product_link_* tables in the databese, seem they contain invalid data.**"

I am not sure about this suggestion. Could any one suggest me the fix for this or any reference link to solve this issue would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: I would try backing up the database and clearing those tables anyway, or at least remove the rows from `catalog_product_link` that relates to the problematic product.

Comment: Ok.. but this will remove all other relations right?

Comment: That depends if you selectively remove rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clear the product_link_* tables in the databese, seem they contain invalid data.

Yes, this helped me... I selectively removed the values as suggested by clockworkgeek.